# Mongodb, aggregate query with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Got two collecetions, tags and persons.

tags model:

```
{
  en: String,
  sv: String
}
```

person model:

```
{
  name: String,
  projects: [
    title: String,
    tags: [
      {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'tag'
      }
    ]
  ]

}
```

I want query that returns all tags that is in use in the person model. All documents.

Sometehing like

```
var query = mongoose.model('tag').find({...});
```

Or should I somehow use the aggregate approach to this?

Comment: You want all the tags in whole application or all the tags for a particular person?
Because if you want to list all the tags without concerning person, you can directly query on tags collection.

Comment: I want the tags in the whole application. All tags existing in project.tags for all persons.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For any particular person document, you can use the [**`populate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) function like

```
var query = mongoose.model("person").find({ "name": "foo" }).populate("projects.tags");
```

And if you want to search for any persons that have any tag with 'MongoDB' or 'Node JS' for example, you can include the query option in the `populate()` function overload as:

```
var query = mongoose.model("person").find({ "name": "foo" }).populate({
    "path": "projects.tags",
    "match": { "en": { "$in": ["MongoDB", "Node JS"] } }
});
```

---

If you want all tags existing in `"project.tags"` for all persons, then aggregation framework is the way to go. Consider running this pipeline on the person collection and uses the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to do a left join on the tags collection:

```
mongoose.model('person').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$projects" },
    { "$unwind": "$projects.tags" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tags",
            "localField": "projects.tags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "resultingTagsArray"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$resultingTagsArray" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "allTags": { "$addToSet": "$resultingTagsArray" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
 ]).exec(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
 })
```

For any particular person then apply a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline as the first step to filter the documents:

```
mongoose.model('person').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "foo" } },
    { "$unwind": "$projects" },
    { "$unwind": "$projects.tags" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tags",
            "localField": "projects.tags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "resultingTagsArray"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$resultingTagsArray" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "allTags": { "$addToSet": "$resultingTagsArray" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
 ]).exec(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
 })
```

---

Another workaround if you are using MongoDB versions >= 2.6 or <= 3.0 which do not have support for the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator is to populate the results from the aggregation as:

```
mongoose.model('person').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$projects" },
    { "$unwind": "$projects.tags" },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "allTags": { "$addToSet": "$projects.tags" }
        }
    }
 ], function(err, result) {
    mongoose.model('person')
    .populate(result, { "path": "allTags" }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4 ));
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake in my post. projects is not an object. It's an array. I've updated the question. Could you look at again?

Comment: You can fix this by prefixing another `{ "$unwind": "$projects" }` pipeline, as in the updated answer.

Comment: Very powerful stuff. Gotta learn this aggregation framework one day. Thx!

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the ```populate()``` option

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDb version 3.2 then you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which performs an left outer join.