# Mongoose sub field aggregation with full text search and project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a **Mongoose** model called **Session** with a field named **course** (**Course** model) and I want to perform full text search on **sessions** with full text search, also I wanna aggregate results using fields from **course** sub field and to select some fields like **course**, **date**, etc.
I tried the following:

```
Session.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: { $text: { $search: 'web' } }
            },
            { $unwind: '$course' },
            {
                $project: {
                    course: '$course',
                    date: '$date',
                    address: '$address',
                    available: '$available'
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { title: '$course.title', category: '$course.courseCategory', language: '$course.language' }
                }
            }
        ],
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                Session.deepPopulate(result, 'course course.trainer 
                  course.courseCategory', function(err, sessions) {
                  res.json(sessions);
            });
            }
        }
    );
```

My models:

- Session

```
    schema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            date: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            },
            course: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'course',
                required: true
            },
            palnning: {
                type: [Schedule]
            },
            attachments: {
                type: [Attachment]
            },
            topics: {
                type: [Topic]
            },
            trainer: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'trainer'
            },
            trainingCompany: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'training-company'
            },
            address: {
                type: Address
            },
            quizzes: {
                type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
                ref: 'quiz'
            },
            path: {
                type: String
            },
            limitPlaces: {
                type: Number
            },
            status: {
                type: String
            },
            available: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: Date,
                default: new Date()
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: Date
            }
        },
        {
            versionKey: false
        }
    );
```

- Course

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        shortDescription: {
            type: String
        },
        duration: {
            type: Duration
        },
        slug: {
            type: String
        },
        slugs: {
            type: [String]
        },
        program: {
            content: {
                type: String
            },
            file: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        audience: [String],
        requirements: [String],
        language: {
            type: String,
            enum: languages
        },
        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        sections: [Section],
        attachments: {
            type: [Attachment]
        },
        tags: [String],
        courseCategory: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'course-category',
            required: true
        },
        trainer: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'trainer'
        },
        trainingCompany: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'training-company'
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            default: 'draft',
            enum: courseStatus
        },
        path: {
            type: String
        },
        cover: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        duration: {
            type: Number,
            min: 1
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Date
        }
    },
    { versionKey: false }
);
```

I am not sure if what I tried is gonna bring me what I want and I am getting this error concerning the **$unwind** operator:

> MongoError: exception: Value at end of $unwind field path '$course'
> must be an Array, but is a OID

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You are missing `$lookup` required to pull course document by joining on course object id from session document to id in the course document. Insert the lookup stage between `$match` and `$unwind` stages. Something like `{
    $lookup: {
        from: "course",
        localField: "course",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "course"
    }
}`. Adjust to use correct collection name, local field and foreign field.

Comment: @Veeram I got this error:  `MongoError: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'`

Comment: My mongoose version is **^4.11.12** if it make a sense.

Comment: `$lookup` stage was added in 3.2 mongo server. Looks like you are not on 3.2 version. Go to mongo shell and run `db.version()` to verify.

Comment: @Veeram mongo version 2.6.11

Comment: This post should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912017/mongodb-aggregate-query-with-lookup

Comment: @Veeram I migrated to version 3.4.2, It seems to be not working as all I get is an empty array every time

Comment: Can you add the models to the post ?

Comment: Your schema looks good to me. What is your collection containing course documents called ? course or courses ?

Comment: @Veeram course collection is **courses**

Comment: Try `{ $lookup: { from: "courses", localField: "course", foreignField: "_id", as: "course" } }`

Comment: It works, I mean I am getting an output but it's not what I expected:
`[
    {
        "_id": {
            "title": "Get Started with Angular",
            "category": "59ce2092aa43630a2eb25f90"
        }
    }
]`

Comment: I want it to give me the **course**, the **date**, **address** and **availability** of the session. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

You are missing `$lookup` required to pull course document by joining on course object id from session document to id in the course document.

`$project` stage to keep the desired fields in the output.

```
Session.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$text": {
        "$search": "web"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "courses",
      "localField": "course",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "course"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "course": 1,
      "date": 1,
      "address": 1,
      "available": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Course is an array with one course document. You can use the `$arrayElemAt` to project the document.

```
 "course": {"$arrayElemAt":["$course", 0]}
```

Comment: It's working fine excepting when adding a **$match** even with a true condition like for example:
 ` {
    $match: { 'available': true }
   } `

Comment: Are you implying it is not working when you add "available" to match stage ? Something like  `{
    "$match": {
      "$text": {
        "$search": "web"
      }, "available": true 
    }
  }` should work.

Comment: No, even only `{ "$match": { "available": true } }` is not working

Comment: Actually, even in the output I am not getting **available** property

Comment: Its hard to speculate. Just check your documents and make sure it matches what you are looking for. May be it is string "true" value. If the issue persists please consider creating a separate question with all the details.

Comment: I find it out, it's my fault: available set to be true by default, but not available in the database