# How can i fetch data like join query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to fetch data from deposit and coin_info collection on which coin id will be 
same in both collections.

can i use populate in this condition? if yes how?

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

 var data=mongoose.Schema({
 user_id:{type:String},
 coin_key:{type:String},
 address:{type:String},
 label:{type:String}
 });

var coin_info=mongoose.Schema({

coin_name:{type:String},
```

_id:{type:String},
    });

```
var deposte_model=mongoose.model('deposit',data);

var get_coin_info=mongoose.model('coin_infos',coin_info);


module.exports.get_deposite_history = 
function(object_id,coin_id,callback) {

var query={user_id:object_id,coin_key:coin_id};

deposte_model.find(query,function(err, teams) {
    callback(err, teams);
});
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `$lookup` aggregate function to join with other collection in mongoDB. doc for lookup funcion https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Comment: i am trying as follow:

Comment: var ccc=deposte_model.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: get_coin_info,
          localField: "coin_key",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }

]);

Comment: is it right way

Comment: yes, enclose get_coin_info with "

Comment: ok but i am not getting result..

Comment: Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [ { '$lookup': [Object] } ],
  _model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'deposit',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: ..................

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912466/3344829

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162207/discussion-between-riya-singhal-and-saravana).