# Mongoose find value from other collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, populate

here is my models:

```
var RaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    owner:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:"user"
    }
});
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { 
        type: String
    }
});
```

Here is an example of my collections:

```
//Races
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b5740c54befec2594ce4cb0"
    },
    "name": "Race1"
    "owner": {
        "$oid": "5b34f870e1eef640f8cb43e4"
    }
}
//User
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b34f870e1eef640f8cb43e4"
    },
    "username":"admin"
}
```

I want to find races whose owner matchs with field **username**. I mean:
"I want to find races whose owner is **admin**"

I'm trying this with:

```
Race.find().populate('users', {username: 'admin'}).exec(function (err, races) {
    ....
}
```

But always the result is the same, the search gives me all races.

### **EDIT 1**

SQL Sentence would be:

```
Select * FROM Races,Users WHERE owner=user._id AND user.username='admin'
```

Or something like that

Comment: How about using the `find` property and specify what you actually want to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from two different collections you will need to use **aggregate** function with **$lookup** ([see the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/))

You can find its equivalent in mongoose ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912017/mongodb-aggregate-query-with-lookup))

Comment: I dont want get data from two different collections. SQL Sentence would be:

Select * FROM Races,Users WHERE owner=user._id AND user.username='admin'

Or something like that

Answer (score 1):

## Finally I did. SOLUTION:

Here is my code:

```
var query=[{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "owner",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "user"
        }
    },{
        "$unwind": "$user"
    },{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                "user.username": username
            }]
        }
    }];
Race.aggregate(query, function (err, races){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

once you get all the races use array method filter

**example**:

```
let adminRaces = races.filter(x=>x.owner['$oid'] === admin._id['$oid'])
```

here's reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter